# Getting Socket.io to work in Android Webview

Tags: express, socket.io, android-webview, cors

I am trying to use **socket.io** inside an Android **Webview**, inside a native Android app. The Android activity file has been updated with;

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/public/index.html");
```

My problem is **loading the socket.io.js libraries from the index.html**:

```
<script src="http://mydomain:port/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

The error I get during the rendering of the webview is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mydomain:port/socket.io... Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I am using a node.js/express server to try and serve the libraries and thought I had configured this to accept cross-origin-resource-sharing (CORS) by setting

```
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
```

Now I am completely stuck! Can anybody recommend a way forward to get socket.io working in this configuration?

Cheers,

Kirbs

Answer (score 1):

why not run service socket.io at activity, try my answer at this

[singleton service socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709783/android-socket-io-switch-activities-without-lost-connection)

I using socket-io.java client library from github

[Gottox](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client)