# Android how to broadcast background notification to current active activity?

Tags: android, singleton, broadcastreceiver

I'm new to android and I know this question has been asked a lot, but I didn't find a good solution.

I have a singleton SocketIO class which keep receiving information at the background. at the same time I have lots of activities doing different stuff.

now what I what to do is when the SocketIO class received a singal, I need to interrupt the current activity and pop up an alert dialog to show the alert Dialog. And when user click on the "yes" button, it goes to a certain activity to do it's work.

Now I put the socketIO client in a singleton class and write a receiver in each activities to receiver notification from socketIO class. But the problem is I have lots of activities doing different stuff, and the receiver in each activities are actually the same. it's kind of a waste of resources and not efficient. Is there any more efficient way to call current running foreground activity from back end non-activity class?

the Singleton SocketIO class and the receiver in each Activities are like in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24691463)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SharedPreferences in your singletons.

This is how you use it

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("NAMETOCALL", "valuetostoreforlateruse");
editor.commit();
```

And this is how you access it for notification

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
sharedpreferences.getString("NAMETOCALL", null);
```

Comment: Mike: Sorry~ I'm not sure i understand your code, maybe I didn't express myself clear. your code seems to get value in singleton class from other activities, right? What I what is a pop up window show the information from singleton class no matter what activity I'm at currently. Do I have to write a receiver at every activities?

Comment: My code does that. Store the value and call it in every class you want it to appear.

Comment: thanks mike, but I hope there's a better way to do that, I don't want to call it in every activities....I hope there's some class can let me to only specify the code in the service class and I dont have to call it in every activties.......I'm currently using the similar way.